# How to make transaction using npm package

Tags: myetherwallet

Using `npm` packages how would you create a transaction on the Ethereum network for 1 ETH to the wallet address `0x8f0ee8bf4596ae4e6c421350159bc723a3afdaa4`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at the github repo for [MyEtherWallet](https://github.com/kvhnuke/etherwallet) to give you an idea on how you can implement such functionality.

There's also a [ReactJS version](https://github.com/MyEtherWallet/MyEtherWallet)